# How to print every item in a multidimenstional array in python

Tags: python, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```py
import os, sys

def fetch_files(directory, suffixes):
     fileList = []
     for _file in os.listdir(directory):
          if os.path.isdir(_file):
             for _fetched in fetch_files(_file, suffixes):
                 fileList.append(_fetched)
         else:                              
             for i in suffixes:             
                 if _file.endswith(i):
                     fileList.append(_file)
                     
    return fileList

print(fetch_files("./", [".png", ".jpg"])
```

I'm kinda new to recursion and don't know why this is not working. I kinda got it working before but it only worked on 2 levels. Can someone please help me out with this?

note: the code is not quite the same because I originally wrote it in a big script and I'm printing it for debug reasons.

Comment: It's probably much easier to use the `glob` module or `os.walk` to find your files in subdirectories.

Comment: I'd look into it.

Comment: To understand recursive, first should understand recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path with the dir name.

```
if os.path.isdir(directory+'\\'+_file):
    for _fetched in fetch_files(directory+'\\'+_file, suffixes):
```

[link to my answer to your question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/kcd7up/how_to_print_every_item_in_a_multi_dimensional/) =)